# Processing ARJ File in Java

Tags: java, compression

Is there any way to process/read/write ARJ compressed file in java without extracting to some directory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7-zip has [Java bindings](http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/) for its c++ apis.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://commons.apache.org/compress/ if you want to stay within a JVM and not rely on native apps